# Product comparison with Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

How can I implement a product comparison with the Drupal Commerce module?

For example, if there is a list of products, will the user be able to click on checkbox of 3 products, and click the "Compare" button to see a table where products, features, and prices are compared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this page could be useful for you: [Product comparison in Drupal](http://jan.tomka.name/blog/product-comparison-drupal). This tutorial explains how to to implement a node comparison with Flag and Views modules: in short creating an Include in comparison per-user node flag, which users will use to mark the interesting nodes. Then, creating a table view with the nodes previously marked.

Comment: there's nothing here mentioned about drupal commerce, but I suppose this will work, right?

Comment: hello john, Is a detailed recomendation about experience of a Drupal developer (jan tomka). sorry but it is not my experience, is a suggestion.

Comment: This is a great explanation and does what it says.

Comment: You should write a summary of what reported in that article, in your answer. Answers that just contain a link are not much helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There's this interesting module, the [Properties](http://drupal.org/project/properties) module, which allows you to do comparisons, but it hasn't anything to do with Drupal Commerce. You could have these properties in any Drupal entity.

> Provides a dynamic properties field that allows to store product properties or similarly structured information. A property consists of an attribute, the name of the property and a value. It belongs to a category.
>
> Properties are stored in a structured way so that they can be compared, indexed, processed and displayed in different ways. By default, a table and a definition list formatter is provided.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I see that the development of this module has stopped since May.

Answer (score 0):

There is module for that

Commerce Comparer

http://drupal.org/sandbox/ymakux/1908654

Comment: You can download it from git: https://drupal.org/project/1908654/git-instructions but bear in mind that is a sandbox marked as obsolete